# google maps v3 kml data not showing

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I am generating a dynamic kml file via php for use with google maps, all my data is stored in a MySQL database, and i generate the kml from that, its working on most of the entries i have and showing the correct boundary data.

However i have one entry that refuses to work, i am getting the following network errors in firebug from the google maps calls, am sure this is why it isnt showing the boundary data

```
http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@205000000&src=apiv3&hl=en-GB&x=1021&y=681&z=11&s=&style=api%7Csmartmaps - Aborted

http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@205000000&src=apiv3&hl=en-GB&x=1021&y=681&z=11&s=&style=api%7Csmartmaps - Aborted

http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@205000000&src=apiv3&hl=en-GB&x=1024&y=679&z=11&s=Galileo&style=api%7Csmartmaps - Aborted

http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@205000000&src=apiv3&hl=en-GB&x=1024&y=681&z=11&s=G&style=api%7Csmartmaps - Aborted
```

I cant for the life of me work out why it des not work for this 1 area Barnet...

The data itself is correct because it works in the fusion table i created:
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1U6gSR5u3L4P3SQxeuDynXp4a0De3X-2_FBcube4#map:id=3

I also know that the KML file is valid as it works for the other locaions i have.

Locations that are working:
[Hounslow](http://2012.reelfilmlocations.co.uk/admin/boroughs/extended/testing.php?id_ctg=193)
[Enfield](http://2012.reelfilmlocations.co.uk/admin/boroughs/extended/testing.php?id_ctg=194)
[Lea Valley Park](http://2012.reelfilmlocations.co.uk/admin/boroughs/extended/testing.php?id_ctg=196)

Location that isnt working:
[Barnet](http://2012.reelfilmlocations.co.uk/admin/boroughs/extended/testing.php?id_ctg=195)

I really dont know how to troubleshoot this, any ideas as to what is wrong would be greatly appreciated. 
(the kml files that are generated can be downloaded using the download button at the bottom of the pages from the above links)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [KML](http://2012.reelfilmlocations.co.uk/KML/KML_Borough.php?id_ctg=195&seed=20130117140001) on that page is invalid.

[feedvalidator](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2F2012.reelfilmlocations.co.uk%2FKML%2FKML_Borough.php%3Fid_ctg%3D195%26seed%3D20130117140001)

[Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2F2012.reelfilmlocations.co.uk%2FKML%2FKML_Borough.php%3Fid_ctg%3D195%26seed%3D20130117140001&hl=en&sll=32.824552,-117.108978&sspn=0.691256,0.883026&t=m&z=10)

Comment: Thanks i had  run it through a validator http://kmlvalidator.com/validate.htm and it came up clean, i see the one above still reports errors, I will try wrapping in <CDATA> Tags...

Comment: @Dizzy Bryan High, how about up-voting and accepting instead of writing "Thanks"?

Comment: @Marcelo i like to check and redo my code and see if an answer solved my problem before i accept an answer, you will see that nearly all of my questions i accept an answer and upvote any replys and comments i find usefull, how about you stop trolling people???

Comment: @Dizzy Bryan High, I'm not trolling, I just get discouraged by how much time I spend on people who ask questions and then do not up-vote good answers. Maybe you're not one of them. My apologies.